# Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[0,1]$. Also, let $\int_0^1{f(x)x^n dx}=0$ for all $n\geq 0$. Prove that $\int_0^1{f^2(x)}=0$.

Tags: analysis

> Let $f(x)$ be continuous on $[0,1]$. Also, let $\int_0^1{f(x)x^n dx}=0$ for all $n\geq 0$. Prove that $\int_0^1{f^2(x)}=0$.

My hunch is that if $\int_0^1{f(x)x^n dx}=0$ for all $n\geq 0$, then $f(x)=0$ in $[0,1]$, which would imply that $\int_0^1{f^2(x)}=0$. However, I don't know how to prove this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: My hunch is you've recently seen the Weierstrass Polynomial Approximation Theorem.

Comment: @DavidMitra- LOL. No I haven't. I'll check it out now though. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First note that if $p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k$ is any polynomial, then $\int_0^1f(x)p(x)dx=0$, since
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1f(x)p(x)dx=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\int_0^1f(x)x^kdx=0.
\end{align*}
Now use the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem. It says that there is a sequence of polynomials $p_n$ which converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,1]$. Since the convergence is uniform, we are allowed to interchange limit and integration, that is
\begin{align*}
0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f(x)p_n(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)\left[\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n(x)\right]dx=\int_0^1f(x)^2dx.
\end{align*}
Since $f^2$ is continuous and non-negative we conclude $f(x)^2=0$ (and hence $f(x)=0$) for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

There is [some theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)
which ensures that you can find a sequence of polynomials $f_n$ such as 
$$
\int_0^1 (f_n - f)^2 \to 0
$$

From this you can prove that $\int ff_n \to \int f^2$. Can you take it from here?