# Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1f(x)x^ndx = 0$ for $n = 0,1,2...$ Prove that $f$ is identically zero on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function on $[0,1]$ and $\int_0^1f(x)x^ndx = 0$ for $n = 0,1,2...$ Prove that $f$ is identically zero on $[0,1]$

This question was a part of a Topology exercise, but I cannot understand what relation it has to Topology. It seems like a real analysis question, where I integrate by parts (?) and show $f=0$ is required for the question to hold. But how to solve this from a topological perspective?

Unless I am understanding the "Prove that $f$ is identically zero on $[0,1]$" part wrong (?)

Comment: @MartinR  Apologies! I typed 1 instead of 0. Fixed It.

Comment: Integration by parts won't work, because you don't know that $f$ is differentiable. Anyway I agree that this is more of a real analysis type of question than a topological one.

Comment: If the Weierstrass approximation theorem is an acceptable solution then this could be closed as a duplicate of (for example) https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1066115/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1961851/42969.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from your hypothesis that, for each polynomial function $P$, $\int_0^1f(x)P(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$. But, by the Weierstrass approximation theorem, there is a sequence $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of polynomial which converges uniformly to $f$. Therefore, $\int_0^1f^2(x)\,\mathrm dx=0$. And now it follows from the continuity of $f$ that $f$ is the null function.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a topological proof as opposed to a real analysis proof.

Comment: It uses the fact that polynomial functions are dense in $C([0,1])$.

Comment: That's real analysis to me.

Comment: @mathworker21 I agree with you, yet for some reason I believe that the OP looks for this kind of answer. But you can post a different answer if you have one

Comment: @Yanko I disagree that the OP was looking for this sort of answer. He/she said "It seems like a real analysis question ... but how to solve this from a topological perspective?"

Comment: @mathworker21 Right, but his "real analysis" approach was integration by parts. We can't know for sure anyway...

Comment: Solutions based on the Weierstrass approximation theorem have been posted before several times, see my above comment.

Comment: @Yanko I don't see the relevance of your first sentence. Look at what I quoted.

Answer (score 3):

This is immediate from Weierstrass Theorem. Since $\int_0^{1}f(x)p(x)\, dx =0$ for every polynomial $p$ we also have $\int_0^{1}f(x)^{2}\, dx =0$ which implies $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a topological proof as opposed to a real analysis proof.

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't know what you mean by a toloplogical proof . Weierstras' Theorem is mentioned in many topology books. It is used to prove separability of $C[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't know; something involving winding numbers.

Comment: Solutions based on the Weierstrass approximation theorem have been posted before several times, see my above comment.